# Does this variant of Multiplicative Linear Logic with mix rule enjoy cut elimination?

Tags: lo.logic, linear-logic, interaction-nets

In Multiplicative Linear Logic (MLL), addition of the mix rule eliminates 'connectedness' from Danos-Regnier criterion. I'm investigating how the criterion changes if we do not distinguish between tensor and par.

Let's take a MLL inference rules with the mix rule and forget the difference between tensor and par:

$$ \frac{}{\vdash A, A^\bot} \;\mathtt{id} $$
$$ \frac{\vdash \Gamma_1, A\quad \vdash \Gamma_2, A^\bot}{\vdash \Gamma_1, \Gamma_2} \;\mathtt{cut} $$
$$ \frac{\vdash \Gamma_1 \quad \vdash \Gamma_2}{\vdash \Gamma_1, \Gamma_2} \;\mathtt{mix}$$
$$ \frac{\vdash \Gamma, A, B}{\vdash \Gamma, A \cdot B} \;\mathtt{par}$$
The tensor rule is obsolete as it can be derived from the mix and par rules:
$$ \frac{\vdash \Gamma_1, A\quad \vdash \Gamma_2, B}{\vdash \Gamma_1, \Gamma_2, A \cdot B} \;\mathtt{tensor} $$

My intuition is that not all proof-structures are valid i.e. some variant of Danos-Regnier criterion for this system still is necessary. The intuition is that it admits cycles but only the trivial ones, not 'real' deadlocks. But I don't know how to formalize it, so I'll move to cut elimination formalization.

The above, might be considered a type system for an interaction net with a single self-annihilating node $ \mu $ (notation defined in the footnote): 
$$ \{\ldots, e \frown \mu (a_1, a_2), e \frown \mu (b_1, b_2), \ldots, \} \rightsquigarrow \{\ldots, a_1 \frown b_1, a_2 \frown b_2, \ldots \}$$

Let's extend standard cut-elimination procedure with one more rule:
the trivial cycle, made from identity and cut only, disappears:

$$ 
\{\ldots, a \frown b, b \frown a, \ldots, \} \rightsquigarrow 
\{\ldots, a \frown a, \ldots \} \rightsquigarrow 
\{\ldots, \ldots \}
$$

Example of a deadlock: $a \frown \mu(a,b)$.

**Questions:**

1. *Does the described type system, when applied in an obvious way to the interaction net, eliminates the possibility of deadlocks?*
2. *Does the type system enjoy cut elimination?*
3. *Are these two questions equivalent?*
4. *Are there any publications about it?*

**Footnote**

Notation for the nets:

- Net is a set of links.
- Variables denote edges.
- $ e \frown \mu(a,b)$ represents an a node $\mu$  with two auxiliary edges $a, b$ and a principal edge $e$.
- Each variable is present in the set *exactly 1 or 2 times*, 1 means it is a 'free edge',
- $\frown$ is commutative.
- Two connected edges are just an edge: $\{\ldots, a \frown b, b\frown c, \ldots \} \rightsquigarrow \{\ldots, a \frown c, \ldots \}$

Comment: [Related question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40805/is-the-set-of-multiplicative-proof-nets-a-proper-subset-of-set-of-well-formed-si?rq=1) and a relevant [Denis Bechet's paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.2.8039&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For question 1, if by "deadlock" you mean "non-trivial vicious circle", then the answer is obviously yes, simply because a non-trivial vicious circle cannot be typed: you will have a cut between a formula $A$ and a formula $F$ containing $A^\bot$ as *strict* subformula, so it is impossible that $F=A^\bot$. But this is kind of trivial: by refusing *a priori* to consider cyclic wires as deadlocks, you are eliminating the only possible typed deadlock, so of course you are deadlock-free...

For question 2, there are definitely problems with your sequent calculus.  First, I assume that you are working with orthogonality defined by $(A\cdot B)^\bot=A^\bot\cdot B^\bot$.  Then, you have that the formula $A^\bot\cdot A$ is essentially self-dual and, since it is provable, you have a proof of the empty sequent. But your inference rules (except cut) still verify the subformula property, which means that there is no cut-free proof of the empty sequent. In other words, you are forgetting the rule
$$\frac{}{\vdash}$$
Without this rule, cut-elimination does not hold. There is a further problem though, namely that you cannot represent the cut-elimination steps inside the sequent calculus: in other words, as a type system, you do not have subject reduction.  For that, you need to consider a unary cut rule:
$$\frac{\vdash\Gamma,A^\bot,A}{\vdash\Gamma}$$
Note that, like the tensor rule, the binary cut rule is derivable from this one (and mix).

For question 3, I assume that you are asking whether the system captures your notion of deadlock-freedom.  Since you are excluding cyclic wires *a priori* (i.e., you are artifically adding a cut-elimination rule that makes them disappear) the the answer is, again, trivially yes: a net normalizes (with your additional reduction rule) to what Lafont calls a *reduced* net (no vicious circle, no active pair) iff it is typable in the above system. This is provable by standard arguments: subject reduction/subject expansion and typability of reduced nets.

For question 4, I doubt anyone has published anything because this system is so degenerate that I honestly do not see what its interest may be.  In fact, one may further simplify the types by eliminating duality altogether: there is no negation, formulas are just
$$A,B::=\alpha\mathrel |A\cdot B$$
and axioms/cuts introduce/eliminate pairs of equal formulas. This system, albeit logically trivial (because of self-duality), has the same normalization property as above. It boils down to the so-called *relational semantics* of MLL, which is applicable to untyped structures too, in which tensor equals par.

Regarding your search for a Danos-Regnier correctness criterion for single-agent nets, there is not much to be said: if you make cyclic wires disappear "by fiat", then the self-dual "typing" above suffices and correctness criteria play no role; if you stick to the standard definitions, then there can be no meaningful correctness criterion: every one-conclusion net cut with itself generates cyclic wires.

Comment: Damiano, thank you for your answer, I learned from it a lot.

Comment: Damiano, do you have a paper that you would recommend as a good intro to relational semantics? Preferably in the context of linear logic.

Comment: Is relation semantics same as  Kripke semantics?

Comment: The relational semantics is not a *truth* semantics (a semantics of formulas, like Kripke semantics) but a *denotational* semantics (a semantics of *proofs*).  It is sort of a degenerate version of coherence spaces.  Unfortunately there is no formal account of it in the literature, except the appendix of [this paper](https://www.irif.fr/~ehrhard//pub/finite.pdf) by Thomas Ehrhard.  In short, if you take the self-dual version of the system I described and collect all the typings you can give with it to a proof $\pi$, the resulting set is (isomorphic to) the relational semantics of $\pi$.